# Unable to change color of RepositoryItemButtonEdit in Devexpress Gridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, button, gridview, devexpress

I have a column in a DevExpress Gridview that consists of Buttons.  I would like to change the color of all the buttons in that column.

Buttons have been created this way:

```
Dim WithEvents buttonAdd As RepositoryItemButtonEdit
buttonAdd = New RepositoryItemButtonEdit
buttonAdd.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.HideTextEditor
buttonAdd.Buttons(0).Kind = ButtonPredefines.Glyph
```

Buttons are put in `GridView1` this way:

```
Dim unbColumn As GridColumn = Gridview1.Columns.AddField("Button!")
unbColumn.VisibleIndex = Gridview1.Columns.Count
unbColumn.ColumnEdit = buttonAdd
Gridview1.OptionsView.ShowButtonMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ShowButtonModeEnum.ShowAlways
```

I have tried:

`buttonAdd.Buttons(0).appearence()`..... but nothing allows me to change the color of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same question is already discussed in the context of the [RepositoryItemButtonEdit how to change the backcolor](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T259733) thread in DevExpress Support Center.
In short, you can't change the colors when using skinning because the skinning is based on images and colors defined in skins. You should either disable skins and then use the Appearance's properties or modify skins.

Comment: The following code was used to add color to the buttons. 


`buttonAdd.ButtonsStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.Flat
            buttonAdd.Buttons(0).Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = True
            buttonAdd.Buttons(0).Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightBlue`